# How to make shape of FAB button to be like triangle

Tags: android

I want to make FAB Button in triangular shape, But usually FAB is in circle shape. How will I achieve it.

Comment: why don't you use ImageView with android:src because floating action button is nothing but ImageView with some special functionality

Comment: do you achieved what you required?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Try to post what you've tried first. The public will not want to type the code for you. Show eventual troubles you are having and you are likely to get good answer.

Comment: Sorry, Im new to android, Ill keep in mind your suggestion , Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

- take triangular shape Drawable and add it
- app:backgroundTint should be "null"

Answer (score 1):

I haven't try this yet, but this is my idea. What if you:

- make transparent to background color of button using property
  **background** or **background-tint**
- add triangle image using property **src**

However, we are not suggested to change the shape of the button. Look this: [Float Action Button](https://material.google.com/components/buttons-floating-action-button.html#buttons-floating-action-button-floating-action-button)